# How to inject script tag into header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zendesk, zendesk-api

**Background**
I am using ZenDesk's Web Widget (Classic) to show restricted content on the page. As per documentation

> You can specify settings for the widget by defining a
> window.zESettings object. Make sure you add any settings before the
> Web Widget (Classic) snippet.

That means `window.zESettings` must be set BEFORE script is loaded. The Web Widget (Classic) snippet is loaded using script URL looks like
`https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xyz`

For restricted content to show inside the widget, I will have to set jwt token to `window.zESettings` and that needs to happen before script is loaded. The jwt token is generated on server.

Zendesk expect that `window.zESettings` needs to be set and the script needs to be loaded on each page. Which is kind of ridiculous because 90+% of the time user would not use Zendesk help on the page.

**Issue**
I would like do it on demand when user clicks on a button.

```
$("#myHelpWidget").click(function () {            
        window.zESettings = {
            webWidget: {
                authenticate: {
                    jwtFn: function (callback) {
                        // Fetch your jwt token and then call our supplied callback below.
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/myaccount/jwtticket"
                        })
                            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                callback(data.Token);
                            })

                    }
                },
                contactForm: {
                    attachments: true,
                    fields: [
                        { id: 'name', prefill: { '*': 'foo bar' } },
                        { id: 'email', prefill: { '*': 'foobar@example.com' } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        };

        // dynamically create script tag here
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.id = "ze-snippet";
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        head.appendChild(s);
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = "https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xyz";
        
        
        //ERROR:  Get error at line below  zE is not defined ****
        zE('webWidget', 'show'); 
        zE('webWidget', 'open');
        zE('webWidget:on', 'close', function () {
            zE('webWidget', 'hide');
        });
                    
    })
```

The code above throws error `zE is not defined`.
Is there a way to inject a script tag into header and wait till its loaded completely. *(Note that jQuery's $.getScript did not work.)*

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001653307-Live-Chat-Script-Resulting-In-Uncaught-ReferenceError

Answer (score 1):

Put all the `zE` calls in the `script.load` event:

```js
var s;
s = document.createElement('script');
s.id = "ze-snippet";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(s);
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xyz";

s.onload = function() {
     zE('webWidget', 'show'); 
     zE('webWidget', 'open');
     zE('webWidget:on', 'close', function () {
         zE('webWidget', 'hide');
     });
}
```